# Calculating distance from centroids

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to calculate the Euclidean distance of a data matrix and a set of centers.

I've used this function:

```
Euclid <- function(df, centers) {
    distanceMatrix <- matrix(NA, nrow=dim(df)[1], ncol=dim(centers)[1])
    for(i in 1:nrow(centers)) {
    distanceMatrix[,i] <- sqrt(rowSums(t(t(df)-centers[i,])^2))
    }
    distanceMatrix
}
```

`df` is the data matrix with points as rows and dimensions as columns. It has 840 points and 11 dimensions.

```
head(df)   

  v1     v2    v3     v4     v5     v6     v7     v8     v9      v10   v11  
1 -0.81  0.24  -0.36  -0.68  -0.51  -0.26  -0.82   0.53   0.19   0.17   0.92
2  1.23  0.24   0.11   0.65   0.67   0.56   0.43  -0.19  -0.31   0.55   0.45
3 -0.81 -0.59  -0.36  -0.35   0.28   0.15   0.02  -0.19   0.68   0.17  -0.02
```

`centers` is the matrix of centers with 12 rows and 11 dimensions.

```
head(centers)  

  v1     v2    v3     v4     v5     v6     v7     v8     v9     v10   v11  
1 0.29   0.09  0.19   0.02   -0.07  0.13  -0.01  0.09   0.02   0.15  0.09
2 0.04   0.03  0.10   0.01   0.01   0.01   0.03  0.01   0.31   0.04  0.45
3 0.07   0.02 -0.02  -0.02   0.48   0.36  -0.66 -0.09   0.21  -0.03 -0.78
```

However, applying the `Euclid` function has resulted in the following error:

```
distsToCenters <- Euclid(df, centers)
  Error in distanceMatrix[, i] <- sqrt(rowSums(t(t(df) - centers[i,  : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I've tried this on matrices with much smaller dimensions and it has worked fine. However, it doesn't seem to working on my current set of data and center matrices.

Would someone be able to let me know what I've done wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`data.frames` are good for handling data. But work differently compared to the `matrix` class. What you have here is a nasty bug that is somewhat counterintuitive. Try to replace `sqrt(rowSums(t(t(df)-centers[i,])^2))` by

```
sqrt(rowSums(t(t(as.matrix(df))-as.matrix(centers)[i,])^2))
# or at the start
df <- as.matrix(df); centers <- as.matrix(centers)
```

A working example:

```
Euclid <- function(df, centers) {
  distanceMatrix <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = nrow(centers))
  df <- as.matrix(df)
  centers <- as.matrix(centers)
  for(i in 1:nrow(centers)) {
    distanceMatrix[, i] <- sqrt( colSums( (t(df) - centers[i, ])^2 ) )
  }
  return(distanceMatrix)
}

tmp1 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5))
tmp2 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(2), y = rnorm(2))

tmp1
tmp2
Euclid(tmp1, tmp2)
```